# What map will let me win a game of Battle City as soon as possible?

Tags: battle-city

In [Battle City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_City_(video_game)) (NES), you could construct your own maps to play.

[image: image of Battle City main menu]

What is the best strategy to create a map to win the game as quickly as possible?

Comment: Do you mean 'to beat that map as soon as possible'? Because making your own map doesn't help you win this game.

Comment: The only useful thing you can do with the map editor is surround your base with impenetrable walls, so it cannot be destroyed. After completing a custom map, the game starts/resumes normal level progression. In this instance, unless ire_and_curses is correct, creating custom maps actually leads to a longer game (+1 level to total game length)

Comment: @Lazer I just noticed that in your screenshot, there is a '© 1980 2007 Namco Ltd.' written in there. Also it states '1.0 beta'. Why is '2007' and 'beta' written in there? From what version of the game did you get that screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Surround your base with concrete, then surround the enemy spawn points (top left corner, top middle, and top right corner) with the blue water tile. The enemies won't be able to move around, but you still get to shoot them. Of course they can shoot you too, so just be careful. This will win you the *map* very quick, but it will not win you the *game* since,if I remember correctly, it takes you back to level 1 after you win your custom map.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my tactic for custom map from my childhood. Yellow dots are spawns of enemies. You just stand at the 'gate' and spam attack, while enemies come to their death.

[image: Tanks]